# Create Cron Job in shared host and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

i want send notification every Minute to my users with laravel framework and shared host ,ssh access not accessible in my host,
i'm so sorry for my english

my command

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Classes\NotificationClass;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Checkreserve extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'check:reserve';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'send notification to all user';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $ss=new NotificationClass();
        $ss->sendNotification();
        $this->info('sende to all');
    }
}
```

my kernel class

```
namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\Checkreserve;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        // Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\Checkreserve::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('Checkreserve')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

and my cron job

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnT9a.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your command to run the `artisan schedule:run`. Note that there is a space after `php` and the path, this tells the cron job to execute the php script which is the artisan file.

```
php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Change your scheduler to

```
$schedule->command('check:reserve')->everyMinute();
```